# How to dynamically append results to a mocked method in Mockito

Tags: java, mockito

I'm originally mocking `java.sql.ResultSet` like this:

```
ResultSet rs = mock(ResultSet.class);
when(rs.next()).thenReturn(true, false);
when(rs.getString(1)).thenReturn("foo");
when(rs.getString(2)).thenReturn("bar");
when(rs.getInt(3)).thenReturn(55);
```

The above code is for mocking a simple one level data mocking, and it's working without any issues.

However, we have more complicated cases in our code where we use ResultSet in multiple method calling levels. Here's a sample code for a nested calling for ResultSet.

```
void level1(){
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()) {
        String a = rs.getString(1);//Expected to return "foo"
        String b = rs.getString(2);//Expected to return "bar"
        int c = rs.getInt(3);//Expected to return 55
    }
    level2();
}
void level2(){
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()) {
        String a = rs.getString(1);//Expected to return "lorem"
        String b = rs.getString(2);//Expected to return "ipsum"
    }
    level3();
}
void level3(){
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()) {
        String a = rs.getString(1);//Expected to return "alice"
        int b = rs.getInt(2);//Expected to return 66
        int c = rs.getInt(3);//Expected to return 77
    }
    level3();
}
```

To mock the method `level1` in the above snippet, we have to write something similar to this

```
ResultSet rs = mock(ResultSet.class);
when(rs.next()).thenReturn(true, false, true, false, true, false);
when(rs.getString(1)).thenReturn("foo", "lorem", "alice");
when(rs.getString(2)).thenReturn("bar", "ipsum");
when(rs.getInt(3)).thenReturn(55, 77);
when(rs.getInt(2)).thenReturn(66);
```

As you can see from the above example, mocking the nested methods is not readable at all.

We are looking for a way to replace the unreadable mocking code with something more redable that will look like this:

```
ResultSet rs = mock(ResultSet.class);
when(rs.next()).thenReturnAndAppend(true, false);
when(rs.getString(1)).thenReturnAndAppend("foo");
when(rs.getString(2)).thenReturnAndAppend("bar");
when(rs.getInt(3)).thenReturnAndAppend(55);

when(rs.next()).thenReturnAndAppend(true, false);
when(rs.getString(1)).thenReturnAndAppend("lorem");
when(rs.getString(2)).thenReturnAndAppend("ipsum");

when(rs.next()).thenReturnAndAppend(true, false);
when(rs.getString(1)).thenReturnAndAppend("alice");
when(rs.getInt(2)).thenReturnAndAppend(66);
when(rs.getInt(3)).thenReturnAndAppend(77);
```

Is there a way in Mockito to achieve that?

I've already tried to use `when().then()` multiple times for the same method, but that overrides the previous mock for that method, and doesn't append values.

I've also tried to use `OngoingStubbing` to accomplish that but it throws an exception saying this is a bad behavior to use `then` on different lines.

I've also tried to create a custom `mock` method to store values in a map and load them from the map later

```
    private Map<Object, Stream> mockingMap;
    protected <T> void whenThen(T method, T value) {
        if(!mockingMap.containsKey(method)) {
            mockingMap.put(mock, (Stream<T>)Stream.of());
        }
        mockingMap.put(method, Stream.concat(mockingMap.get(method), Stream.of(value)))
        when(method).thenAnswer(e -> {
            mockingMap.get(method).next()
        });
    }
```

And will use this method like this:

```
whenThen(rs.getString(1), "foo");
whenThen(rs.getString(1), "lorem");
```

The issue with this implementation is that the value of `method` in `whenThen` method doesn't represent the mocked method `rs.getString(1)`, which means that calling `rs.getString(1)` two times will result in two different values for the `method` parameter.

My first question is: Is there any built in method in Mockito that has a similar behavior to `thenReturnAndAppend`.
My second question is: If there's no similar method to `thenReturnAndAppend`, then how can I pass a unique key to the `whenThen` method that represents the method that we are trying to mock?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, you can do so using `iterator-style stubbing`:

https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.24.5/org/mockito/Mockito.html#stubbing_consecutive_calls

> Stubbing consecutive calls (iterator-style stubbing) Sometimes we need to stub with different return value/exception for the same method
> call. Typical use case could be mocking iterators. Original version of
> Mockito did not have this feature to promote simple mocking. For
> example, instead of iterators one could use Iterable or simply
> collections. Those offer natural ways of stubbing (e.g. using real
> collections). In rare scenarios stubbing consecutive calls could be
> useful, though:

```
 when(mock.someMethod("some arg"))
   .thenThrow(new RuntimeException())
   .thenReturn("foo");

 //First call: throws runtime exception:
 mock.someMethod("some arg");

 //Second call: prints "foo"
 System.out.println(mock.someMethod("some arg"));

 //Any consecutive call: prints "foo" as well (last stubbing wins).
 System.out.println(mock.someMethod("some arg"));
```

---

Your example would then look similar to:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = null;

ResultSet mockResult1 = Mockito.mock(ResultSet.class);
Mockito.when(mockResult1 .next()).thenReturn(true);
Mockito.when(mockResult1 .getString(1)).thenReturn("foo");
Mockito.when(mockResult1 .getString(2)).thenReturn("bar");
Mockito.when(mockResult1 .getInt(3)).thenReturn(55);


ResultSet mockResult2 = Mockito.mock(ResultSet.class);
Mockito.when(mockResult2 .next()).thenReturn(true);
Mockito.when(mockResult2 .getString(1)).thenReturn("lorem");
Mockito.when(mockResult2 .getString(2)).thenReturn("ipsum");
Mockito.when(mockResult2 .getInt(3)).thenReturn(55);


Mockito.when(stmt.executeQuery()).thenReturn(mockResult1).thenReturn(mockResult2);
```